# Android toggle button change state on scroll listview

Tags: android, toggle

Hello I am working with android.I had created a custom list view with toggle button in each row.But the problem is when I scroll the list view the toggle button state changes. How can I solve this problem. Please help me . Thanks in advance :) here is my code

```
 class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            ArrayList<String> name,status;

            dataListAdapter() {
                name = null;
                status = null;


            }

            public dataListAdapter(ArrayList<String> text,ArrayList<String> text1){
                name = text;
                status=text1;

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return name.size();
            }

            public void updateResults(ArrayList<String> text) {
                name = text;


                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public Object getItem(int arg0) {

                return null;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {

                return position;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View row;

                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cmplnt_single_item, parent, false);
                TextView name1;


                name1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);



                name1.setText(name.get(position));
                ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
                if(status.get(position).equals("0"))
                   {
                       toggle.setChecked(false);  
                   }

                else
                {
                     toggle.setChecked(true);  
                }
                  toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        if (isChecked)
                        {





                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on at "+position, 5000).show();
                        }
                            else
                            {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "off at "+position, 5000).show();

                            }
                    }
                });


                return (row);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference to get the togglestate and save the toggle state when the swich is toggle